# looping though values based on a condition

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a function in python that checks if the data in the dataframe is following a certain structure
in my case i need to ensure that the id column is structured like this ID0101-10

here is my code but it is not working, i keep getting an indexing error:

```python
i = 0 
for i in df["id"]:
    if ('-' in df["id"]):
        df["id"].iloc[i] = df["id"].iloc[i]
        i += 1
    else:
        df.drop(df["id"].iloc[i])
        i += 1
```

```html
if you're curious about my data, its like this:
id            name 
ID0101-10     John    
ID0101-11     Mary 
8454          Test
MMMM          MMMM
ID0101-01     Ben
MN87876       00.00
```

i am trying to clean my data by dropping the dummy values

EDIT: i get this error 
TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: droping dummy data. as in keep records with John, Mary and Ben

Comment: so dropping all the rows where id is not of the form "ID0101-XX"?

Comment: exactly, i've been trying but this is my first time cleaning such messy data

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['ID0101-10', 'ID0101-11', '8454', 'MMMM', 'ID0101-01', 'MN87876'],
                   'name':['John', 'Mary', 'Test', 'MMMM', 'Ben', '00.00']})

result = df[df['id'].str.startswith('ID0101-')]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
          id  name
0  ID0101-10  John
1  ID0101-11  Mary
4  ID0101-01   Ben
```

As a general rule, you rarely need to loop over pandas dataframes, it's almost always faster to use native pandas functions.

For more complex matches you can use regular expressions: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html

Comment: See this page of the Pandas documentation for more information on the `.str` methods: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html?highlight=strings

Comment: never thought it would be this simple! works like a charm. Thank you so much

Comment: @HDDSG also, remember to use the `pandas` tags for these sorts of questions!